# How to enable AirWatch MDM functionality for apps deployed on AppStore

Tags: ios, mdm, airwatch

Airwatch currently provides three options:

1. Internal Apps
2. Public Apps
3. Purchased App (VPP)

I want to enable MDM for public apps, I have installed SDK, but it is not getting authenticated with the public apps, but gets authenticated with the Internal Apps.

MDM is required to check whether the device is enrolled or not.

Currently, my app is live on Appstore.

So, please provide me solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  What sort of authentication do you want in your app? Show the relevant code.

Comment: What do you mean by "enable MDM for public apps"? Do you mean you want to manage public apps with the help of MDM?

Comment: Yes. I want to add App Store app and configure App Config. Its ok I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Public Apps (Apps that deployed on App Store)

To enable App Config or MDM for public Apps, Please follow below steps :

1. please search for app name when adding an app in AirWatch, don't enter URL of App Store app (because it will not provide you option to enable MDM).
2. From search results select App you want to add in AirWatch.
3. After adding an app, please select save button.
4. When you go to "Assignment" tab,  enable MDM, and also you can enable "App Config".
5. If you are using App Config, then add keys and values.
6. From the example given in apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html you can able to implement App Config and you will receive key and values in NSUSerDefaults when app launch.